# Generic method with a custom generic action delegate parameter which itself has a ref parameter

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, ref

[EDIT] I Do apologize, this construct ***is*** working as it should.

here is my delegate type and my generic method:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public delegate void RefAction<TRef, in T>(ref TRef refArg, T arg);

    public static void MyMethod<T, TRef>(List<T> param1, 
                                         ref TRef refVar, 
                                         RefAction<TRef, T> refAction)
    {
        foreach (T item in param1)
        {
          // DO something with item

          refAction(ref refVar, item);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I call it:

```
public class CClass : List<CItem>
{
    public void CMethod(A a, B b, ref V[] stdVariables)
    {
        SomeClass.MyMethod<CItem, V[]>(this, 
                                       ref stdVariables,
                                       (ref V[] variables, CItem cItem) => cItem.CMethod(a, b, ref variables));

    }
}
```

which compiles fine.

It is a bit odd though, that I am passing refVar to MyMethd and yet it is a parameter of refAction.

is it possible to do this in a cleaner way?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it not doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: Everything looks to be working fine.  If there is a problem you'll need to 1) explain the problem that you are having.  "It doesn't work" is not a sufficient problem statement. 2) provide code that can demonstrate that problem.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the array by reference in the first place?  It's an array; a reference type.  Are you really allocating new arrays and assigning them to the variable in these methods?  if you are, you should probably be using a `List` instead, in which case you wouldn't need to be passing *that* by reference.

Comment: The cause may be to do with the fact that since `ref` is not (and can't be) part of the delegate, the type is being passed by value to the delegate and then passed by reference to the method, which would only be observable as a pass by value.